# Существует ли оболочка для WIN Command Promt?

Tags: windows, cmd

Существует ли оболочка для Command Promt?

Например, что бы подсвечивались возможные команды при наборе текста и т п.

Comment: для cmd точно нет, возможно есть редактор для `*.BAT` файлов с таким функционалом, но я их всегда в блокноте правил. Для PowerShell может быть что-то есть.

Comment: https://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_studio о какую штуку нашел. Правда денег стоит не мало.

Comment: [ConEmu - Windows console with tabs](https://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) [PyCmd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pycmd/)

Comment: Notepad++, AkelPad - текстовые редакторы с подсветкой синтаксиса, но команды сами они не предлагают.

Comment: Для PowerShell из бесплатных и интегрированных в Windows - Windows PowerShell ISE. Альтернатива - PowerGUI